# How do you change the origin of a radial gradient in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I want to change the origin of a radial gradient in Inkscape (so that it's not in the centre of the shape, but off to one side). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply double click inside the radial gradient area.

Answer (score 1):

> http://en.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/ch021_gradient-tool/
>   Radial gradients work as colored circles with the color transition beginning at the center. Three handles are available : the square one is the center of the gradient, and the circle ones change the radius of the gradient. When the radius is the same for both circle handle, the gradient is perfectly circular. To move the placement of a radial gradient in the object, drag the square handle.

Answer (score 1):

Hover over the square handle in the center of the gradient then hold shift and drag.